# How do I set up donations with the Donate App?

Tags: facebook

I have added the donate button to my page, SaveMMJ.  I have not been able to figure out how to allow donations.  I cannot find a way to give my paypal information.  I have tried to donate myself to test it and paypal says there is an error.  Can you please give advice for what to do after adding the app so that people can give to the cause?

Comment: I don't believe Facebook has a 'donate' button, you'll need to clarify what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about http://www.facebook.com/donateapp?  I have it installed on my page, and you just need to ensure your PayPal account is a Business or Premier level.  I don't think it works on regular accounts, so we upgraded ours (for free) at PayPal.com